# Open/Close Dojo Menu with mouse over event

Tags: menu, dojo, mouseover

Does anyone know how to open/close a dojo dropdown menu with the mouseenter/mouseleave events?

Actually, I've successfully opened the menu with the mouseenter event, however, the menu wont close when the mouse moves off the button (or the subsequent opened menu).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the menu closes when it loses focus, so your mouse enter/leave events should focus on and off the menu, respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
 var projectsDropdown = new dijit.form.DropDownButton({
                        label: "Projects",
                        name: "projects",
                        dropDown: projectsMenu,
                        onMouseOver: function()
                        {this.openDropDown();},
                        onMouseLeave: function()
                        {this.closeDropDown();},
                        id: "projectsButton"},"projectsDropdown");
```